# How to switch between full and half-width input for Windows 10 Japanese IME?

Tags: discussion

How to switch between full and half-width input for Windows 10 Japanese IME?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work since I am not on Windows 10, but clicking on the icon in the taskbar that indicates the mode of typing (katakana, hiragana, romaji etc.) I can select halfwidth from the menu that appears after that.

My options are:

- Hiragana
- full width katakana
- full width romaji
- half width katakana
- half width romaji

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

I can’t check right now but IIRC it was Shift-CapsLock. You can also just type the word in any kana and press F7 to make it full width katakana or F8 for half width.